# TeXStudio: ! LaTeX Error: File `apacite.sty' not found

Tags: packages, texstudio

I have a file in which I (want to) use `apacite` for my references. However, TeXStudio does not seem to be able to find the package, while I know it is installed on the system.

```
apt-file -x search '/apacite.sty$'
```

returns:

```
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/apacite/apacite.sty
```

so I know it is installed. Then on Windows 7 TeXStudio has no problem finding the package (running MiKTeX 2.something for package management) and the file compiles without errors.

So my question would be: How do I convince TeXStudio to also check for packages in texmf-texlive?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What's the answer to `kpsewhich apacite.sty`?

Comment: It does not return anything. Should I navigate to a specific folder or use any options?
edit: Thnx for the welcome.

Comment: First of all try doing `sudo texhash`.

Comment: It returns
``texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R...``
``texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN...`` 
``texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... ``
``texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... ``
``texhash: Done.``

Then ``kpsewhich apacite.sty`` returns nothing (within ubuntu terminal).

Comment: Do you have two tex systems?

Comment: I have Texstudio and tex-live installed, but ``/usr/share/`` contains: ``tex-common``, ``texlive-base``, ``texlive-bin``, ``texmf``, ``texmf-texlive`` and ``texstudio``.

Comment: Can you add the complete output of `sudo texhash` to your question, please? Reading it in comments is difficult.

Comment: Likely on a problem of TeXstudio itself, but of paths. Does it compile when you're starting pdflatex (or whichever compiler you use) from the command line?

Comment: I finally fixed it by installing TexLive 2013 http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F1092%2Fhow-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNF_eIi2JL4grCg0hG0CSDFjtKFf1w